# Combine into a flat list in python

Tags: python, numpy

---

I want to :

1. Iterate through the elements of the first list, `a`
2. Multiply them by the elements in the second list `b`
3. Then subtract the elements in a third list `c`

e.g:

```py
a = [1,2]
b = [0,1]
c = [1,2]
output = [-1, -2, 0, -1, -1, -2, 1, 0]
```

Comment: Please show what you’ve tried already.  In `numpy` this is *very* simple and a little research will quickly reveal the solution.

Comment: Do you **have** to use numpy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

a = [1,2]
b = [0,1]
c = [1,2]
o = [-1, -2, 0, -1, -1, -2, 1, 0]

A = np.array(a)[:, None, None]
B = np.array(b)[None, :, None]
C = np.array(c)[None, None, :]
O = (A * B - C).ravel()
print(O)
# [-1 -2  0 -1 -1 -2  1  0]

np.allclose(o, O)
# True
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [1,2]
b = [0,1]
c = [1,2]

result = [((x*y)-z) for x in a for y in b for z in c]
print(result)
```

Here is one possible answer

Comment: while this solution works it is not very readable.

Comment: I disagree my friend. For this kind of short operation, I think it does and is more pythonic.

Comment: Note that the OP is a junior developer so I am not sure that 3 level list comprehension is the kind of code he can understand easily.  He can cut/paste it - but the question is (in my eyes) - can he understand this code?

Comment: @tmdavison I assume that the OP is a junior developer since it is a 'junior question' - dont you think so?

Answer (score 0):

Try that

```
a = [1,2]
b = [0,1]
c = [1,2]
result= []

for i in a:
    for j in b:
        aux = i*j
        for z in c:
            res = aux - z
            result.append(res)

print(result)
```